# Bugzilla: How to get an rss feed for bug comments?

Tags: rss, bugzilla

I can see where to get an rss feed for the BUG LIST, however I would like to get rss updates for modifications to current bugs if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking for is the subject of this enhancement bug:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=256718

but no one seems to be working on it.

My first guess is that the way to do it is to add a template somewhere like `template/en/default/bug/show.atom.tmpl` with whatever you need.  Put it in `custom` or an extension as needed.

If you're interested in working on it or helping someone with it, visit channel #mozwebtools on irc.mozilla.org.

Answer (score 4):

This is quite high up when searching via Google for it, so I'm adding a bit of advertisement here:

As Bugzilla still doesn't support this I wrote a small web service supporting exactly this. You can find its source code [here](https://github.com/kaueraal/bugzillatoatom) and a running instance [here](https://bugzillatoatom.affine.space/).

Comment: Great project! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution, but with the resolution of [bug #255606](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=255606), Bugzilla now allows listing all bugs, by running a search with no criteria, and you can then get the results of the search in Atom format using the link in the bottom of the list.

From the [release notes for 4.2](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/page.cgi?id=release-notes.html#v42_feat_other):

> **Configuration:** A new parameter `search_allow_no_criteria` has been added (default: on) which allows admins to forbid queries with no criteria. This is particularly useful for large installations with several tens of thousands bugs where returning all bugs doesn't make sense and would have a performance impact on the database.

Answer (score 0):

[RSS-Bridge](https://github.com/RSS-Bridge/rss-bridge) supports generating RSS/Atom feeds containing updates for individual bugs. There are plenty of public RSS-Bridge instances out there, so I'm not linking to any specific one.